# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in custom onTouch function in React container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I am trying to create a Todo list using react material-ui and the latest version of react.js (15.0.0 at this moment).

In the container named `TodoList`, I am trying to pass/assign the `onTouchAction` to the component `Todo` that takes a reference to the `onTouchAction`, which will toggle its completion status.

In the following code, the `toggleTodo(todoId)` is an action method that sends data to the reducer, however, I got the following error when trying to a get reference to the `dispatch` function int he props of the `TodoList` container, which looks like the `this.props` is undefined according to the error in the console. That being said, I can print out the `this.props.dispatch` as a function in the life cycle functions such as `componentDidMount()`.

```
onTouchAction(todoId) {
    console.info('on touch item, todoId: ', todoId);
    let dispatch = this.props.dispatch; // this causes error: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

    dispatch(toggleTodo(todoId));
   }
```

**Error in the console:**

```
Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

So, my question is why `this.props` is undefined in my custom function but is present in the life cycle event functions?

Comment: Make sure that the `onTouchAction` is bound either in the constructor or in the props of the Todo component (i.e. `onTouchAction={this.onTouchAction.bind(this, todoId)}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use React in ES6, you will have to bind your handlers.

This can be done in the constructor:

```
export default class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onClickAction === this.onClickAction.bind(this);
  }

  onClickAction(e) {}
}
```

or you could do it in all places you use it.

```
export default class Component extends React.Component {
  onClickAction(e) {}

  render() {
    return <input onClick={this.onClickAction.bind(this)}/>
  }
}
```

or you could use ES6 fat arrows:

```
export default class Component extends React.Component {
  onClickAction = (e) => {}

  render() {
    return <input onClick={this.onClickAction}/>
  }
}
```